# Reading logcat programmatically with filters

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I've the following code but it only outputs first line of the logcat "----beginning of main", rest of the logcat is not captured.

When I run same "logcat -d -s myapp:I" from commandline, it shows several lines.

```
        String command = "logcat -d -s myapp:I";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Reading: " + line); // just prints "----beginning of main"
          lines.add(line);
        }
```

Why do I get one line output?

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that running `logcat` in production may not be reliable, as that is not part of the Android SDK.

Beyond that, you only get log messages from your own app (and a small subset of system ones), because you do not have rights to access all of the logs, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Its not a production app, its for debugging purposes. either way your answer isn't an answer

Comment: @Taranfx: It is an answer. The reason why you are not getting the messages is that your process does not have rights to the messages that it is not getting. This has been the case [for nearly five years](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html). If you are running on a rooted device, AFAIK you can use `su` to run `logcat` and get the same content as you would from a development machine.